# 1/4 MFL to 1/4 MFL does not fit 1/4 FFL to barb. Why?

Tags: kegging, closed-transfer

For my co2 closed transfer setup, I was expecting to be able to screw those 2 items together (male to female):
https://www.ontariobeerkegs.com/Stainless_Steel_Flared_Union_1_4_MFL_x_1_4_MFL_p/ss-1-4-m-mfl-x-1-4-m-mfl.htm

https://www.ontariobeerkegs.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=ss-swivel-nut-5-16

But the adapter (1/4 MFL to 1/4 MFL) is too big to fit the 1/4 FFL to barb.

Why? Shouldn't 1/4 MFL fit properly 1/4 FFL? Do I miss something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fittings are properly called 45 degree SAE flare fittings, you could check their dimensions against the standard (https://www.ryco.com.au/technical/thread-connector-identification/sae-threads/ ) to be sure about what you actually got sent. By rights, they should fit. If they don't, then at least one of them is not what you ordered. I'd measure them against the standard and then shoot Ontario Beer Kegs a message to get it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had no idea such a website existed. I contacted OBK and they suspect the supplier made a mistake (probably after double checking the 2 parts don't fit together on their end). They are getting in touch with him and will let me know.

Comment: No worries, that sounds like a great outcome. I think it would help, in situations like this, if the brewing world used industry standard terminology - searching for MFL yields very little, because it's not a real thing.