# Keg connectos: what are "MFL"/Barb/SAE threading fitting sizes?

Tags: keg

Frankly only shops I have visited fail completely in providing an indication about what exactly they are selling when it comes to keg fittings.

I have read [this answer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/23497/14242) to another question, which was asking less generally then this, also about the fittings for keg connectors.

My question is: What are the different standards related to those fittings, what, and more over how can I measure which fitting I have?

Bonus: Is it only my impression that online shops do extremely poorly with regards to providing any, or if so accurate description about the fittings.

Example: I have two fittings [image]
I can tell that the outer diameter of the red fitting is about `12.60mm / 0.496inches` and of the black one it is about `10.86 mm / 0.427 inches`.

Part of an answer could also be which of those fittings sizes/descriptions like `MFL`, actually exists, or are merely customarily used, but are not actually a "thing".

Answer (score 2):

Definitions:

- MFL - male flare, (FFL female flare)
- Barb - barbed fittings, used with polyethylene tubing and a hose clamp. Standards: [NSF-51](https://www.techstreet.com/nsf/standards/nsf-51-2017?gateway_code=nsf&product_id=2019439)
- SAE is the [Society of Automotive Engineers](https://www.sae.org/about/) - flare angle 45°
- AN is [Army/Navy fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN_thread), [JIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIC_fitting) is the industrial counterpart of SAE J514 - flare angle 37°

SAE J512/4 - 12.7mm is 1/2-20 and 9.5mm is 3/8-24 or 11.1mm is 7/16-20. (10.86mm is not one of the available sizes).

Source:

- Automotive Tube Fittings [J512_201705](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j512_201705/)

> Note: For sizes 3/16 to 3/8 and 1/2 to 3/4 the flare type fittings depicted in Figures 1A to 3C are identical with the corresponding refrigeration tube fittings specified in SAE [J513](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j513_199901/). Special size combination fittings 3/16 to 3/8 and 1/2 to 3/4 shall be as specified in SAE J513.

- Hydraulic Tube Fittings [J514_201201](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j514_201201/)

See also:

- [JIC 37° Flare & Uno (O Ring Boss) Threads](https://www.ryco.com.au/technical/thread-connector-identification/jic-37-flare-uno-o-ring-boss-threads/)
- [SAE 45° Flare – SAE J512](https://www.ryco.com.au/technical/thread-connector-identification/sae-threads/)

[image: 37°][image: 45°]

It appears that those are 37° MFLs (J514).

Comment: Hi Rob, this is quite some information you have put together. My question originated with the challenge that is the variety of threadings available and hence the needed terminology and ways to identify a threading. I will reread you answer and attempt to see if I can corroborate and identify that it is a J514. thanks already a lot and I will accept your answer gladly as soon as I found the time to reread it and check the part :). thank!